# Trying to call a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code! The initial macro works however I am trying to create a macro that calls the first macro once a value in column A in the worksheet "List of Assts" is changed. It is not working and I'm pretty frustrated as to why?

```
Sub RenameSheetsBasedOnList()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Set the worksheet where the list is located
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List of Assets")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet 'List of Assets' not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Initialize i to 2 to start renaming from the third sheet
    i = 2

    ' Loop through each cell in column A and rename sheets
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A5:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i + 1).Name = Left(cell.Value, 31) ' Limit to 31 characters for sheet name
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Error renaming sheet '" & cell.Value & "'.", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox "Sheets have been renamed based on the list.", vbInformation
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    
    ' Define the range of cells to monitor for changes (e.g., column A from A5 to the last row)
    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("A5:A" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is within the monitored range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then
        ' If a change is detected, run the renaming macro
        Application.Run "RenameSheetsBasedOnList"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Drop the `Application.Run` you can just call the sub with `RenameSheetsBasedOnList` and make sure the worksheet change event is in the sheet's (presumably List of Assets) code module not a regular module.

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Is it run-time error? I would suggest to remove the 2nd `On Error Resume Next`. Otherwise, all exception in renaming sheet is ignored.

Comment: so take of the quotation and get red of application.run. It will run with just the name of the macro?

Comment: the initial macro runs however for the second macro is supposed to run when a value in column A is changed however that is not working'

Comment: Run `Application.EnableEvents = True` in VBE immediate window, then change a cell to trigger change event.

Comment: fyi - not an answer. The `On Error GoTo 0` just above `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` should be just above `i = i + 1`. Otherwise `Err.Number` will always be zero. Be aware 99.999999% of the time you see `On Error Resume Next` it will be incorrectly implemented.